# How to populate a Gravity Forms Custom Post Field (dropdown type) with custom taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm trying to save a custom post type from the frontend using Gravity Forms (v2.0.6). This post type has custom fields expecting a term ID.

One of the fields is about a "Food Type", and I have like 5 terms on that taxonomy. I have tried with a simple Dropdown field, which allows to "Populate with a Taxonomy" (or a Post Type), but this field type can't be saved as a custom field of the custom post type.

So, what I want is to have this function:

[image: Populate with a Taxonomy]

[...] available in the "Custom Field" field type.

This field needs to show the term name, but the option value needs to be the term id, because the custom field in the post type expects the term ID.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions about the workings of a specific plugin are better directed at the plugin's author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who needs help with this, here's my solution.

With the Gravity Forms hooks `gform_pre_render`, `gform_pre_validation`, `gform_pre_submission_filter` and `gform_admin_pre_render` I was able to populate the dropdown fields with dynamic data.

Despite this is not too user friendly, we can define specific CSS classes to have this done and avoid populate fields that we don't want to.

- Take a look to the structure of the [Form Object](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/form-object/) to see how the field types are called and how to target them on the next point.
- Check the how-to: [Dynamically Populating Drop Down Fields](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/dynamically-populating-drop-down-fields/)

Basically what we do is create a function that renders the form. But first, as I mentioned above, to avoid populate the incorrect fields, we validate that is the correct field type (**Important**: with custom fields, the `type` is `custom_field` instead `select` [as the tutorial describes]. To target custom fields of type dropdown/radio, set the `type` to `custom_field` and the `field_type` to `select`), and the correct CSS class.

Then, instead of using `get_posts`, we use `get_terms` to retrieve the terms.

Hope this helps someone.